# Weird http -> https redirection although not configured

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, redirection, domain

I am running Apache 2.2.15 (CentOS 6.6) with a HTTP-only domain

demo.xml-director.info

Using wget I can retrieve the content properly

```
 wget -S http://demo.xml-director.info
--2015-01-05 13:31:41--  http://demo.xml-director.info/
Resolving demo.xml-director.info (demo.xml-director.info)... 176.9.146.28
Connecting to demo.xml-director.info (demo.xml-director.info)|176.9.146.28|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: Mon, 05 Jan 2015 12:31:41 GMT
  Server: Zope/(2.13.22, python 2.7.6, linux2) ZServer/1.1
  Content-Length: 20227
  Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
  X-Ua-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
  Content-Language: en
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
Length: 20227 (20K) [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html.4'
```

However Chrome/Firefox always change the request from http to https
because of HTST. However for this particular domain there is no HSTS configured.

The server runs SSL for www.xml-director.info with enabled HSTS support.
However there is further alias here that would map demo.xml-director.info to www.xml-director.info.

How can this problem be resolved.

VHOst for www.xml-director.info:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.xml-director.info
    ServerAlias xml-director.info

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/15742445repl_2.crt
    SSLCertificateCHainFile /etc/httpd/certs/15742445repl_2.ca-bundle
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/certs/zopyx.com.key

    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/xml-director.info.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/xml-director/landing-v1

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"

    <location "/">
        Options +Indexes
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "X-Requested-With,Content-Type"
    </location>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias www.xml-director.com 
    ServerAlias www.xml-director.info
    ServerAlias www.xml-director.de
    ServerAlias xml-director.com
    ServerAlias xml-director.info
    ServerAlias xml-director.de

    RedirectPermanent / https://xml-director.info/
</VirtualHost>
```

and for demo.xml-director.info

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  demo.xml-director.info
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:12020/VirtualHostBase/http/demo.xml-director.info:80/xml-director/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]
    RewriteRule ^/$    http://127.0.0.1:12020/VirtualHostBase/http/demo.xml-director.info:80/xml-director/VirtualHostRoot/$1 [L,P]

    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/demo.xml-director.info.log combined
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/xml text/plain text/css text/javascript

    CacheRoot /tmp/cache
    CacheEnable disk /
    CacheIgnoreCacheControl on

    KeepAliveTimeout 15
    KeepAlive on

    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 day"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 10 day"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 10 day"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 day"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 10 day"
    ExpiresByType text/html  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType text/html  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType text/css  "access plus 10 days"

    <Location "/">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Doesn't happen for me on Chrome or Firefox. Are they maybe caching the redirect for you from a previous configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Strict-Transport-Security - includeSubdomains

The problem is the scope of the HSTS header, it includes all subdomains. If accessing `http://demo.xml-director.info` with a browser *first* it'll work fine.

However, upon first access to `https://xml-director.info/` or `https://www.xml-director.info` the browser will receive a HSTS header for all subdomains set to expire way in the future (in two years...?) and therefore will not attempt to connect to any (sub)domain over http again until the header expires.

Incidentally, this header has no effect on cli tools such as `wget` and `curl`.

### Don't include subdomains

If there are *any* subdomains that should be accessed over http - do not use `includeSubdomains`. Instead, if you want to use the HSTS header, restrict it to the accessed domain only (which is the default behavior):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.xml-director.info
    ServerAlias xml-director.info

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000"
```

### Fixing unwanted HSTS headers

A browser which has received a HSTS header has no means of clearing it itself, it will [always attempt to access the domain over https](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/HTTP_strict_transport_security#How_the_browser_handles_it), which if there is no response means it's stuck in limbo.

To correct the current situation of existing browsers (assuming it's not a "just me" problem) it's necessary to expire the HSTS header over a https connection. i.e.:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName *.xml-director.info

    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0"
    RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Or equivalent. In this way the HSTS header is cleared, and http access is restored.